# If Statements wrapped around of each other dont work

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have a little problem, that involves if statements.

```
function voegelfelder(){
            var va = document.getElementById("voegel").value;
            if(va >= "41"){
                alert("Number too high"); 
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("CB").hidden = true;
                document.getElementById("CRB").hidden = false;
                if(va >= "1"){ 

                    document.getElementById("v1x").hidden = false;
                    document.getElementById("v1y").hidden = false;
                    document.getElementById("v1r").hidden = false;
                        if(va >= "2") {

                            document.getElementById("v2x").hidden = false;
                            document.getElementById("v2y").hidden = false;
                            document.getElementById("v2r").hidden = false;

                            if(va >= "3") {
                                document.getElementById("v3x").hidden = false;
                                document.getElementById("v3y").hidden = false;
                                document.getElementById("v3r").hidden = false;

                                if(va >= "4") {
                                    document.getElementById("v4x").hidden = false;
                                    document.getElementById("v4y").hidden = false;
                                    document.getElementById("v4r").hidden = false;

                                    if(va >= "5") {
                                        document.getElementById("v5x").hidden = false;
                                        document.getElementById("v5y").hidden = false;
                                        document.getElementById("v5r").hidden = false;

                                        if(va >= "6") {
                                            document.getElementById("v6x").hidden = false;
                                            document.getElementById("v6y").hidden = false;
                                            document.getElementById("v6r").hidden = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                    }

                }
              }
            }
        }
```

In that example I was checking if the Number in the textfield was 1 or if it was 2 or 3 or 4..., and if it was 3 for Example it should do everything that it does in 1, 2 and 3. That worked but if i typed 5 in there it said "Number too high" but thaht should only happen if the number is more than 40.
By the way I have everything that it needs like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 1 X" id="v1x" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 1 Y" id="v1y" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 1 Richtung" id="v1r" hidden="hidden"><br>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 2 X" id="v2x" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 2 Y" id="v2y" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 2 Richtung" id="v2r" hidden="hidden"><br>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 3 X" id="v3x" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 3 Y" id="v3y" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 3 Richtung" id="v3r" hidden="hidden"><br>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 4 X" id="v4x" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 4 Y" id="v4y" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 4 Richtung" id="v4r" hidden="hidden"><br>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 5 X" id="v5x" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 5 Y" id="v5y" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 5 Richtung" id="v5r" hidden="hidden"><br>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 6 X" id="v6x" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 6 Y" id="v6y" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 6 Richtung" id="v6r" hidden="hidden"><br>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 7 X" id="v7x" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 7 Y" id="v7y" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 7 Richtung" id="v7r" hidden="hidden"><br>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 8 X" id="v8x" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 8 Y" id="v8y" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Vogel 8 Richtung" id="v8r" hidden="hidden"><br>
```

Comment: I would **highly** recommend looking into switch statements https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare strings and numbers, make sure the things you're comparing have the same type otherwise you are subjected to various [rules of conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) that aren't always clear.

You can use `parseInt` to get an integer from your string input, and use integers in your code to compare:

```
var va = parseInt(document.getElementById("voegel").value);
    if(va >= 41){ //notice how the "" is gone
       alert("Number too high"); 
    } else{
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing **strings**. `"5"` is indeed `>` `"41"`, because when you compare strings, you're doing it lexicographically. It's a letter-by-letter process that stops as soon as it finds letters that don't match. Since `"5"` is `>` `"4"`, `"5"` is greater than *any* string starting with `"4"`.

Parse the number from the user, and type the numbers in your `if` statements as numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

When you type in `5` and it says number too high, that is a good indication that you are doing a string comparison (since you are comparing it against `41`). You have to convert it to an integer first, i.e.:

```
var va = +document.getElementById("voegel").value;
```

By adding a `+` at the front, you are coercing its type to `Number`. Also, there is no need to perform excessive if/else nesting. If you want each number to apply to all selectors preceeding it (e.g. `3` will unhide 1, 2, and 3), you can use the following logic:

```
function voegelfelder(){
    var va = document.getElementById("voegel").value;

    // Maximum cutoff at 41
    if(va >= "41"){
        alert("Number too high");
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById("CB").hidden = true;
    document.getElementById("CRB").hidden = false;

    // Iteratively loop through all numbers before
    for (var i = 1; i <= va; i++) {
        document.getElementById("v" + i + "x").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("v" + i + "y").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("v" + i + "r").hidden = false;
    }
}
```